# What does the [XmlAnyAttribute] return on Windows Phone as XmlAttribute is removed?

Tags: .net, xml, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, xml-serialization

I asked this question on MSDN: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/01017fbd-e7ab-4f9a-922b-228bd6158363/what-does-the-xmlanyattribute-return-on-windows-phone-as-xmlattribute-is-removed?forum=wpdevelop

According to the MSDN docs ([http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/system.xml.serialization.xmlanyattributeattribute(v=vs.105).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/system.xml.serialization.xmlanyattributeattribute%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)):

XmlAnyAttributeAttribute "Specifies that the member (a field that returns an array of XmlAttribute objects) can contain any XML attributes." and then "Apply the XmlAnyAttributeAttribute to a field that returns an array of XmlAttribute or XmlNode objects."

However, the XmlAttribute and XmlNode types aren't available on Windows Phone.

I am busy working to port a .NET 4.0 to windows phone, but it does some XML deserialization steps. I am hoping to do minimal code changes, and then get the Unit Tests to pass, before any major changes.

Is there a way to do this, or is another way required?

**UPDATE**

I am looking for the XmlDocument, XmlElement version of the XmlAttribute. This is what is actually returned.

Take this XML:

```
<Group xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
       xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
       GroupType = 'Technical' GroupNumber = '42' GroupBase = 'Red'>
    <GroupName>MyGroup</GroupName>
</Group>
```

and this type:

```
public class Group
{
    [XmlAnyAttribute]
    public XmlAttribute[] UnhandledAttributes { get; set; }
    [XmlElement]
    public string GroupName { get; set; }
}
```

and this code:

```
XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Group));
Group obj = ser.Deserialize(new StringReader(xmlString));
```

Using a console app (net45), the `UnhandledAttributes` array property will have 3 items, one for each attribute on `<Group>`.

What type of array do I use for Windows Phone?